# Attached properties to avoid custom controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've heard about the possibility to use attached properties to avoid writing a custom control in WPF.
Could you explain me how or address me to a tutorial?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found by myself the answer to my question: attached behaviors. They are a way to extend the functionality of a control without writing a new one and are based on a specific use of attached properties.
I found two interesting articles and I attach them below for those of you who are interested in:
[Elad's WPF Blog](http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/attached-behavior/)
[Josh Smith's article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I definitely think that the answer you found yourself is valid but for additional info explaining the Attached property pattern (In plain English as I wasn't too thrilled with Josh Smith's Article). Took 5 min to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2008/05/07/the-attached-behavior-pattern.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments) and it cleared things up for me quite a bit. Gave me the quick and dirty of it.